# Python/Tkinter dynamically update label

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am currently trying to make a GUI to an existing python program using Tkinter. The program gives the user two options from which the user must choose to either accept or decline. Before using Tkinter the options were placed in the terminal and awaited for a raw_input. (y/n). How can I make this so the canvas text updates with the new data and awaits for the users button click?

To make my question more specific: How can I run another programs code while the Tkinter mainloop is running and make these two interact?

Example code below.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(500,550))
root.wm_title("Tkinter test")

BtnFrame = Frame (root)
BtnFrame.pack(side = BOTTOM)
BtnFrame.place(y=450, x=20)

canvas_1 = Canvas(root, width = "200", height ="300")
canvas_2 = Canvas(root, width = "250", height ="300")
canvas_1.pack(side = LEFT)
canvas_2.pack(side = RIGHT)

textfield_1 = canvas_1.create_text(100,50)
textfield_2 = canvas_2.create_text(100,50,)


def update_textfiel_1(text):
   global textfield_1
   canvas_1.delete(textfield_1)
   textfield = canvas.create_text(100,50,text = text)

def update_textfiel_2(text):
   global textfield_2
   canvas_2.delete(textfield_2)
   textfield1 = canvas1.create_text(100,50,text = text)



 Accept = Button(BtnFrame, text="Accept", width=25)
 Decline = Button(BtnFrame, text="Decline", width=25)

 Accept.pack(side = LEFT)
 Decline.pack(side = RIGHT)

 root.mainloop()
```

Comment: the `command` option to the `Button` constructor is probably what you want. Otherwise [events](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/events.html) and `Canvas.bind`.

Comment: what would the updated text be?

Comment: The updated text would be something a loop function in the original program passes to the Tkinter program. I have tried both `command` and `Canvas.bind` with no success... @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen

Answer (score 0):

First off you have some inconsistent variable names in your `update_textfiel` functions, you can greatly simplify it by using `.itemconfigure` ([documentation for methods on canvas widget](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas-methods.html))

```
def update_textfiel_1(new_text):
   canvas_1.itemconfigure(textfield_1, text=new_text)

def update_textfiel_2(new_text):
   canvas_2.itemconfigure(textfield_2, text=new_text)
```

If I understand correctly you want a way to have a function that will simply wait for the user to press one of the buttons and then return the result, this is very easy with `tkMessageBox`:

```
question = """Do you accept {}?
if you say no you will instead get {}"""
#this message can GREATLY be improved
# But I really don't understand what you are using it for...

def user_confirmation(name1, name2):
    response = tkMessageBox.askyesno("Accept or Decline",question.format(name1,name2))
    print(response)
    if response: # == True
        return name1
    else:
        return name2
```

I have not yet found a way to make a blocking function that works with the window you have currently...

Comment: I don't need the canvas_1/2 to display text "accepted/declined". I need another program to wait for the user to click accept/decline and then continue based on the users decision. Imagine a function                         `def user_confirmation(name_1,name_2): answer = raw_input("Accept/Decline")  if(answer == 'Accept'): return name_1 else: return name_2`. This program would somehow pass name_1/2 to be displayed in canvas_1/2

Comment: If this answer didn't help you then I clearly don't understand what you are asking, you may just need to use [`TkMessageBox.askyesno`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/tkMessageBox.html) or similar to replace your `raw_input`.  Otherwise please add more information to your question like what the `Accepted` and `Declined` buttons should actually do.

Comment: ah, the edit to your comment has cleared up my confusion, give me a moment to edit my answer...

Comment: This seems correct but what about the original program? It does not run while the mainloop of the Tkinter program is running...